# Getting the size of an image

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am currently changing textures with cocos2d using this

```
CCTexture2D* tex = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:
                        someImage.png];

[someSprite setTexture: tex];
```

But the issue is the image I send it to

```
[someSprite setTexture:tex withRect:someRect
```

How do I get the size of the image or get the rect size to set the CCSprite to with the texture.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
 urSprite.contentSize
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.0/interface_c_c_texture2_d.html use `tex.contentSize` as a `CGSize` or make a `CGRect` by `CGRectMake(0,0,tex.contentSize.width,tex.contentSize.height);`

Comment: I need to change the image of an already created sprite like the way you mention

Comment: Edited the answer, is this whant you need?

Comment: rather than tex.contentSize, can't you just do tex.boundingBox and skip the CGRectMake step?

Answer (score 0):

I think you were looking for `tex.pixelsWide` and `tex.pixelsHigh`. These are the dimensions of your texture in pixels.

Example:

`[CCSprite spriteWithTexture:tex rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, tex.pixelsWide, tex.pixelsHigh)];`